What is the American equivalent of the British phrase "get on for" in the sense of move toward a specific time?
Can you please tell me what is the American equivalents of the British phrase get on for in the sense of move toward a specific time? For example:

It's getting on for two weeks since I moved to the city.

I've looked on the internet to see if there are answers, but I couldn't find anything.

Don't overstate the AmE/BrE difference here. As this chart shows, although It's getting on for... / It's nigh on... are somewhat more common in BrE, it's not like they're unknown in AmE. Certainly the meaning will be perfectly clear to any halfway competent native Anglophone Americans. Such usage distinctions are falling away these days anyway.

Yes, getting on for is also AmE.

There are numerous idiomatic ways to phrase that sentence in American English - in other words, there's probably no single American English equivalent.
Here are some versions that sound natural in American English, or at least in my dialect of Pacific Northwest American English:

It's coming up on two weeks since...
It's fast approaching two weeks since...
It's been almost two weeks since...
It's almost two weeks since...
(Soon) it's going to be two weeks since...
(Soon) it'll be two weeks...


As a Brit, these all seem perfectly reasonable alternatives to the example given.

Great answer, but it is missing the one tha first came to mind when I read this question: "going on" as in "It's going on three weeks since she left me". Is that version not as common as I think it is?

We murkins have something close:

It's getting on a week since I moved to the city.

We wouldn't involve the preposition for.
As Secretary of Labor under President Bill Clinton, Robert B. Reich, writes in the introduction to his memoir Locked in the Cabinet:

It's getting on a year since I left the cabinet.

